# Simple Java workflow engine

Tags: java, workflow, rule-engine

We are currently working on a project where user can book appointments for a business.
Now each business can have a different process flow for taking a booking and also notifying users about booking status.
e.g workflow 
one business my choose to send 2 reminders, while another may choose to send 1 reminder
One business may not allow refunds if the booking is payed in advance.

We currently have this configured per business in a Database, but to scale this to different types of businesses we are looking an implementing a process flow engine where we can design the process flows for a particular business. So when a booking comes in the business will adapt to the workflow designed for it.

Any suggestions on how to go about this, should we look at implementing a simple xml workflow configuration where classes are loaded and executed using reflection. Or should we look at using an existing open source workflow/rules engine in Java.